# respect __all__ variable with jedi-vim

Tags: jedi-vim

Is it possible to configure `jedi-vim` to respect `__all__` variable inside a module (like `__init__.py`)? So, when I use autocomplete on an imported package, anything inside which is not listed in the `__all__`, and is not a special variable/method, is hidden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does not work and will not work in the near future. Reason: I'm the author.

It's quite complicated to understand `__all__`, because it can basically be generated by any Python code.

I would probably accept a pull request, but only if it works with numpy.